# Problema de linkagem "undefined reference"

Tags: c++, compilação, cmake, biblioteca-estática

Estou tentando compilar uma biblioteca dinâmica que usa uma biblioteca estática.
Estou usando o cmake e o problema que estou tendo são erros na linkagem, onde  os métodos da biblioteca estática estão dando erro de "undefined reference".

O que estou tentando compilar é esse projeto [i9corp/i9corp-voip-sdk](https://github.com/i9corp/i9corp-voip-sdk), que usa o pjsip.

Se eu compilo no Linux (Debian) a compilação e linkagem não dão erro e ao final é gerado o meu arquivo.so, porém se eu compilo no Windows (usando o MinGW) da os erros de undefined reference em todos os lugares onde eu tenho chamadas de métodos da biblioteca estática.

Já tentei setar o caminho do meu MinGW na mão (no cmake) para ele achar os includes e libs, mas não mesmo assim não da certo.

No trecho abaixo [arquivo completo disponível no github](https://github.com/i9corp/i9corp-voip-sdk/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt) o i9corp-voip-sdk é a minha biblioteca dinâmica e o pjproject é uma biblioteca estática que está no diretório **./third-parties/pjsip** as demais bibliotecas wsock32 ws2_32 crypto ssl pthread eu coloquei para tentar resolver o problema, mas não tive sucesso.

Só que seu eu tentar gerar no Windows um uma biblioteca estática no lugar de uma biblioteca dinâmica dá certo. Só da erro se eu tentar gerar a biblioteca dinâmica.

```
target_link_libraries(i9corp-voip-sdk pjproject wsock32 ws2_32 crypto ssl pthread )
```